# How to return the index position and not the value?

Tags: c++, return

I have the following

```
int index = 0;

for (int i = start; i < end; ++i)
{
    cout << spot.at(i) << ' '; // prints 190 2 94
    if (spot.at(i) > spot.at(index)) // finds the greatest value which is 190 so gives back 0 bc spot.at(0) has the highest value
    {
        index = i;
        cout << index;
    }
}
return index;
```

so when I compile I get 190 instead of the index which is 0. If I do not put the return max I get 0 but I need to return the index with the greatest value so I have to include "return". It was working fine but then it keep fluctuating, so sometimes it works other times it doesnt. Now I tried it again with these values129 55 161 67 107 187 164 102 72 135 197 197 start = 0 and end = 11 but it keeps giving me 197 instead of the index which is 10. If I print index it does give me 10 but when I return index it gives me nothing. Still not quite sure whats going wrong, thanks your help is appreciated.

Comment: In addition to `max`, have another variable to track the index at which `max` was last updated. Or just use [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) and be done with it.

Comment: You cannot use same variable max for both value and index, you need two different ones.

Comment: @buendia What is the type of spot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to track both the `max` value, and the index that the `max` value is located at. Then, when you find a new `max`, you update both the `max` and the `maxIndex`.

```
int max = spot.at(0);
int maxIndex = 0;
for (int i = start; i < end; ++i)
{
    cout << spot.at(i) << ' '; // prints 190 2 94

    if (spot.at(i) > max) // find the greatest value
    {
        max = spot.at(i);
        maxIndex = i;
    }
}
return maxIndex;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int max_index = 0;
for (int i = start; i < end; ++i)
{
    cout << spot.at(i) << ' '; // prints 190 2 94
    if (spot.at(i) > spot.at(max_index)) // find the greatest value
    {
        max_index = i;
    }
}
return max_index;
```